# Undefined property: Blog::$pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing [this PHP Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUeU3.png) in my code:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>      Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Blog::$pagination
>
> Filename: controllers/Blog.php
>
> Line Number: 41

```
Backtrace:

File: E:\xampp7.0\htdocs\scrape\application\controllers\Blog.php
Line: 41
Function: _error_handler

File: E:\xampp7.0\htdocs\scrape\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

[image: Some PHP Code]
[image: More PHP Code]

Comment: where did you load your $this->load->library('pagination');?

Comment: Post code as **text**

Answer (score 0):

```
function index(){
        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
        $config['total_rows'] = 200;
        $config['per_page'] = 20;
        //other declairation
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        //other declairation
        $x['page'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
}
```